How to change the view of a json file in VS-code for editing is BUT without formating it?
Example:
The RPG-MAKER MV and MZ data/*.json files are formated as On-Liners.
If I format them with VS-Code extensions,
then their content will be set into many lines (each with a line-number).
And when I open the RPG-Maker it cause issues.
Info: I tried also formating and reformating.
-
When I drag&drop one of those files in my browser I got this:

but it is not editable.
A)
Is there a wrap-methode available for JSON in VS-CODE
to get an editable view - a view like in my browser ?
B)
If there is a solution to get this view by wraping that would be nice.
If it is possible to get this view by default for all JSON files in VS-Code it would be even better.
C)
Because I am switching between JSON and js coding and I am used to the coloring of VS-CODE
it would be a problem for me to use something else than VS-CODE.
I read all of this and more:
How do you format code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)?
Is there a way to view JSON files automatically prettyfied in ...
enter link description here
But those posts are all about formating not about 'wraping' of JSON files.

Why not use built-in features of VSC? Just type F1 + Join Lines or F1 + Format Document.

@Aleksej Vasinov - Because after formating the RPG-Maker can not read them anymore. The RPG-Maker has not a search&replace function there you need to change everything 'manually'. If I want to search&replace via VS or VSC only some (not all) matches of the search then it is difficult....
So having only the (tree-)view of the json would be perfect.
